# Optimize table to reduce index size

Tags: mysql, indexing, data-modeling

I have this schema which saves chat messages. Currently I have about 100k rows which is about 5.5MB of  data. Index size is 6.5MB. When data size was ~4MB index size was ~3MB so it's growing *exponentially*?

```
CREATE TABLE `messages` (
  `id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `author` int(11) unsigned DEFAULT NULL,
  `time` int(10) unsigned DEFAULT NULL,
  `text` text,
  `dest` int(11) unsigned DEFAULT NULL,
  `type` tinyint(4) unsigned DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  KEY `history` (`author`,`dest`,`id`) USING BTREE,
  KEY `messages_ibfk_1` (`dest`),
  FULLTEXT KEY `msg` (`text`),
  CONSTRAINT `au` FOREIGN KEY (`author`) REFERENCES `users` (`id`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE,
  CONSTRAINT `messages_ibfk_1` FOREIGN KEY (`dest`) REFERENCES `users` (`id`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=105895 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

The main query that I'm running against this table and that I've tried to optimize it for is when I need to show paginated history for a chat between 2 people

```
SELECT id, time, text, dest, type, author 
FROM `messages` 
WHERE (
    (author = ? AND dest = ?) OR (author = ? AND dest = ?)
) AND id <= ? ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT ?, 25
```

The other queries for history are identical except they have additional filters for a search term or date range.

Is there anything that can be done to reduce index size and maintain optimal performance?

Comment: Why do you think index size has anything to do with performance? Are your queries running slow? After all, if you had no indexes, then you would save a lot of space, but your queries would be a lot slower, so obviously having an index is something of a space-performance tradeoff, and by having the index at all, you've expressed a desire to have performance at the expense of space.

Comment: Your index might be larger than the table itself if MySQL is leaving some unfilled space in the btree in anticipation of future inserts.

Comment: By the way you could decrease the size of your index and improve query performance by storing "user1" and "user2" instead of "author" and "dest," ordering the two users alphabetically, and making "user1" the first user and "user2" the second. So if you want to find conversations between Mark and Alice, Alice will always be "user1" and Mark will always be "user2." Then you can add another column to indicate whether "user1" is the author or recipient.

Comment: @WillisBlackburn in response to your first comment - I agree but when my index becomes larger than my actual data that seems like a bit of a turn off for the trade for me. 2 - is there any way I can confirm this, currently index is 1.3MB larger than the data. 3 - I don't see what's the relevance between column names and index size, also my users are stored as integers not sure what you meant there.

Comment: I don't think that your index is larger than your data. The 5.5MB you see probably does not include the size of the "text" column, because text columns are stored separately from the main table data. After all if you have 100K messages and they're only taking 5.5MB total, including all the metadata like ID, author, recipient, date, etc., they'd have to be very short messages.

Comment: One cannot infer exponential growth from two data points: `index_size = (7*data_size - 19) / 3` would yield the same results, and is clearly linear.  Indeed, B-Tree indexes have O(*n*) space.

Comment: @WillisBlackburn yes they are mostly very short messages less than 10 characters on average. I'm pretty certain text column is contained in this report.

Comment: About my last comment. I was incorrect in saying that using "user1" and "user2" would shrink your index; it won't because you'll still have the same number of rows in the index. But it will improve your query performance because instead of searching for "author = 'Mark' and dest = 'Alice' or author = 'Alice' and dest = 'Mark'" you can just search for "user1 = 'Alice' and user2 = 'Mark'" and avoid one btree lookup.

Comment: Okay, if you're sure 5.5MB is correct, then just don't worry about it and focus on whether or not your queries are performing well. Honestly you have so little data that your queries are going to be really fast no matter what. Maybe you're planning for more? If so then load up however many messages you're going to have and see where you are then.

Answer (score 1):

Don't worry about the growth of the indexes.  It is probably a fluke; certainly not "exponential".

Assuming the main issue is performance of

```
SELECT id, time, text, dest, type, author 
FROM `messages` 
WHERE (
    (author = ? AND dest = ?) OR (author = ? AND dest = ?)
) AND id <= ? ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT ?, 25
```

I see three techniques that will help significantly:  Change `OR` to `UNION`, deal with `LIMIT` in `UNION`, and don't use `OFFSET` for pagination.

```
        ( SELECT id, time, text, dest, type, author 
            FROM `messages` 
            WHERE author = ?  -- one author & dest
              AND dest = ?
              AND id < ?    -- where you "left off"
            ORDER BY id DESC
            LIMIT 25
        ) UNION ALL
        ( SELECT id, time, text, dest, type, author 
            FROM `messages` 
            WHERE author = ?  -- the other author & dest
              AND dest = ?
              AND id < ?     -- same as above
            ORDER BY id DESC
            LIMIT 25
        )
        ORDER BY id DESC
        LIMIT 25;           -- get the desired 25 from the 50 above
```

[*Pagination discussion*](http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/pagination) explains why the `OFFSET` should be removed.  It discusses other techniques, including using 26 (in all three places) instead of 25 so that you know if this is the 'last' page.

On the first iteration, `AND id < ?` could be left off.  Or (simpler), you could substitute a very large number.

Your index (`author`,`dest`,`id`) is optimal for my formuation.

This complex formulation will shine as `messages` gets bigger and/or the user pages farther through the list.

Comment: This formulation touches at most 50 rows (plus writing 50 to tmp and rereading 50), regardless of table size or page number.  The original formulation touched most or all of the rows, always.

Comment: Thank you for this answer, it was most helpful - especially the part about avoiding using offset for pagination, I have come across this problem in the past. However the question was about whether this index size is acceptable and how to reduce it because IMH(noob)O having an index larger than my data seems out of hand - that's why I will not mark the answer as accepted.

Comment: Also something I thought was worth pointing out - running the original query from the question without offset returns in 1ms however getting the same results with union returns in 50ms. I remember I tested this also when I was designing the table and that used to be the case back then as well - `OR` outperforms `UNION` many times.

Comment: 1ms sounds like the Query cache kicked in.  Try it with `SELECT SQL_NO_CACHE ...` to avoid the QC.

Comment: I have _never_ seen a runaway index.  I _have_ seen odd patterns as the table grows.  Also, `FULLTEXT` grows somewhat differently than plain `INDEXes`.

Comment: Try the `OR` with author and dest values that are _not_ near the end of the table.

Comment: One way to test the performance is:  `FLUSH STATUS; SELECT ... ; SHOW SESSION STATUS LIKE 'Handler%';  My formulation should show small multiples of 25; your formulation may show 25, or anything up to the size of the table.